# Looking for a way to map a function over a 2D Lisp array

Tags: arrays, common-lisp

All of the map functions like `mapcar`, `mapcan`, `mapc`, etc require lists as their inputs. I am working with 2D arrays, and would prefer to not mess with the rank of my arrays given the often large sizes (50,000 x 1,000 sometimes).

I need a way to apply a function like `(log n)` to each element in the 2D array and yield a resulting 2D array.

Any help or direction is much appreciated.

Working in AllegroCL (Common Lisp)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you need is a combination of

- [`dotimes`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_dotime.htm)
- [`array-dimensions`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_ar_d_1.htm)
- [`make-array`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_mk_ar.htm)
- [`array-total-size`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_ar_tot.htm)
- [`row-major-aref`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_row_ma.htm)

Something like this:

```cl
(defun array-map (function array
                  &optional (retval (make-array (array-dimensions array))))
  "Apply FUNCTION to each element of ARRAY.
Return a new array, or write into the optional 3rd argument."
  (dotimes (i (array-total-size array) retval)
    (setf (row-major-aref retval i)
          (funcall function (row-major-aref array i)))))
```

Example:

```cl
(defparameter a (make-array '(2 3) :initial-contents '((1 2 3) (4 5 6))))
a
==> #2A((1 2 3) (4 5 6))
(array-map #'sqrt a)
==> #2A((1 1.4142135 1.7320508) (2 2.236068 2.4494898))
a ; does not change!
==> #2A((1 2 3) (4 5 6))
```

You can also use `array-map` similar to [`map-into`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_map_in.htm):

```cl
(array-map #'1+ a a)
==> #2A((2 3 4) (5 6 7))
a   ; modified, no new storage is allocated
==> #2A((2 3 4) (5 6 7))
```

**Note** that `array-map` will work on any array dimension, from vectors to matrices to 10d &c.

**Exercise**: implement `array-multi-map` accepting a function of any number of argument and any number of arrays, so that

```cl
(array-multi-map #'+ #A((1 2 3) (4 5 6)) #A((11 22 33) (44 55 66)))
==> #A((12 24 36) (48 60 72))
```

**PS**. The whole [CLHS Chapter 15 Arrays](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/15_.htm) or [CLtL2 Chapter 17 Arrays](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/Groups/AI/html/cltl/clm/node157.html) is worth studying.

Comment: It might be good to let the user specify the element type for the new array.

Comment: @jkiiski: I thought about it, but decided against it. If the user wants this level of control, he can pass `retval`. Inferring the array type from the argument array type may prevent the `sqrt` example from working because the input array may be specialized to integers.

Comment: This is great. Thank you. I like that it is very simple and easily implementable despite more complicated functions.

Answer (score 0):

For one-dimensional arrays (vectors) MAP or MAP-INTO can be used directly.  For multi-dimensional arrays we need to extract the vector containing the elements first.  For this Common Lisp has displaced arrays, which can be understood as additional references to elements of a given array.

```
(let* ((a (make-array '(3 4) :element-type 'double-float :initial-element 100d0))
       (ad (make-array (array-total-size a) :displaced-to a :element-type 'double-float))) 
  (map-into ad #'log ad) a)
```

> #2A((4.605170185988092d0 4.605170185988092d0 4.605170185988092d0
> 4.605170185988092d0)
> (4.605170185988092d0 4.605170185988092d0 4.605170185988092d0
> 4.605170185988092d0)
> (4.605170185988092d0 4.605170185988092d0 4.605170185988092d0
> 4.605170185988092d0))